# Updating my website for IE10

Tags: dtd, internet-explorer-10

The following html (taken from Debugger on IE10 on Windows 7)

```html
<td id="newTextIcon">
    <a class="Menu" onmouseout="delayhidemenu();" onclick="return dropdownmenu(this, event, menuNewCode, "80px");" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_top">
        <img width="16" height="16" align="left" class="MenuImg" alt="New" src="images/new.gif" border="0"/>
        New 
        <img width="6" height="3" align="MIDDLE" alt="" src="images/sort_down.gif" border="0" vspace="4"/>
```

is rendered as

[image]

What is the underlying change in thinking that causes the HTML to be rendered differently -  so that I can fix it so that when run in Document Mode: Standard, the button looks like on the right?

Comment: Without the CSS and preferably a way to run the code, such as a jsFiddle, it will be difficult to debug. Would it be possible to provide a demo?

Comment: I added a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gordon613/yvvQ7/ (I didn't do the images properly but you can get an idea by looking at the boxes) If you run the fiddle in IE and you click New, then the left image is not pressed. If you run IE in IE5 Quirks mode, then you will see that if you click New, the left image is included and looks nice [jsFiddle does look somewhat strange however...!]